# How to automatically select font that can display provided text in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx, fonts

I am developing a JavaFX application. Part of it is a virtual keyboard that needs to be able to **display characters which may not be present in the default font**. I need to be able to **detect when** characters are **not supported** by JavaFX font.

My initial idea was to use `java.awt.Font#canDisplayUpTo` method and search through all available fonts using `GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAllFonts()` and this way get a font name to create a JavaFX `javafx.scene.text.Font`.

It turns out that the `java.awt.Font#canDisplayUpTo` returns -1 (meaning all characters are supported) even when the derived JavaFX font does not support provided String. I think this is caused by the fact that the `java.awt.Font` is actually backed up by a Composite Font when default font is used - at least that is what I see when I debug my code.

```java
private static Font defaultFont = Font.getDefault();
public String getFontName(String text) {
        //try default font
        java.awt.Font defaultFontAwt = new java.awt.Font(defaultFont.getName(), java.awt.Font.PLAIN, 16); //defaultFont.getFamily() produces the same result
        if (defaultFontAwt.canDisplayUpTo(text) == -1) {
            //this is always the case :(
            return defaultFont.getName();
        }
        //search through all available fonts
        GraphicsEnvironment e = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        java.awt.Font[] fonts = e.getAllFonts();
        for (java.awt.Font font : fonts) {
            if (font.canDisplayUpTo(text) == -1) {
                return font.getName();
            }
        }
        //Failed to find font that is able to display text
        return defaultFont.getName();
    }
```

My approach appears to be faulty because `defaultFontAwt` is a composite font containing more than the `defaultFont`. It seems to me that I cannot simply create `java.awt.Font` from `javafx.scene.text.Font` and vice versa.

**Is there any other way to detect unsupported characters using `javafx.scene.text.Font` (preferably without using AWT)? If not, is it possible to not create a composite `java.awt.Font` from default javafx font?**

I encountered this issue when running my application on my arch linux and displaying dead characters like dead caron ( ̌) using monospaced font.

Thank you very much for reading this and for your help.